# How to add multiple div dynamically with append child having different id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add div on clicking add button.
on clicking add button the div is created with the 
class name ui modal and 
**id test.**
For multiple div created the same id gets added.
I need to give different ID for Each additionally added div.

**How can I generate different ID using append child.**

Also I need to get the tree structure with parent child and sibling node.

```js
function add_div(){
var div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.className = 'ui-modal';
div.id = 'test';
div.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';
div.textContent = 'Hello world.';
}
```

```css
 .ui-modal{
     width: 200px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
  <input type="button" value="DELETE">


 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

After running this above code And inspecting i am seeing each additionally added div having same ID.

How to generate separate ID?

Comment: Why use an ID at all here? Just use the `className`

Comment: I need different id so that i can further add div, like tree structure.I am trying to create the folder like tree structure as given in this link http://filer.vregistry.com/jsfiler/.   Also  I need to create a table simultaneously in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a counter outside `add_div` and append it into `id` everytime you create a `div`

```js
var counter = 1;

function add_div(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    
    div.className = 'ui-modal';
    div.id = 'test' + (counter++);
    div.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';
    div.textContent = 'Hello world.';
}
```

```css
.ui-modal{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
  <input type="button" value="DELETE">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.This is what I need.I need different id so that i can further add div, like tree structure.I am trying to create the folder like tree structure as given in this link http://filer.vregistry.com/jsfiler/.   Also  I need to create a table simultaneously in the database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the length of elements with class `img` to use that as the suffix to the `id`:

```js
function add_div(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.className = 'ui-modal';
  div.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg').length;
  div.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';
  //div.textContent = 'Hello world.';
}
```

```css
.ui-modal{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
  <input type="button" value="DELETE">
</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.msg').length; Can you please explain me this.

Comment: @JasmineJoseph, this will give you the total number of elements added with class `img`

Comment: Now i have added a div with classname UI-MODAL and id TEST-0.....How to add a child div to the test-0 ,  similar to this link http://filer.vregistry.com/jsfiler/

Comment: @JasmineJoseph, selector will be somthing like `document.querySelectorAll('.UI-MODAL#TEST-0')`